ADO YAML Pipelines | How to get secret variable from a variable group based on the value of another variable
In my project, i can get the value of a variable defined inside a variable group like this, without no problem
steps:
      - checkout: none
      - bash: |
          echo $(shared-smtp-user)

But then, later in the code, i need to put into files the value of some variables from a variable group, and i do something like this
parameters:
    # The targetVariables to put inside secrets/, for example
    # targetVariables:
    # - shared-azure-devops-pat
    # - shared-ldap-password
    # - shared-ldap-user
    # - shared-smtp-user
  - name: targetVariables
    type: object

jobs:
  - job: echo_secret_files
    displayName: ️ Echo secret files
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - bash: |
          echo "Echoing targetVariables into secrets/"
          echo "using targetVariables ${{ convertToJson(parameters.targetVariables) }}"
          mkdir -p ./secrets/
          echo $(shared-smtp-user) # THIS WORKS !!!
        displayName: Display information about the secrets being used
      - ${{ each variableName in parameters.targetVariables }}:
          - bash: |
              echo $SECRET_VALUE > ./secrets/${variableName}.txt
            env:
              SECRET_VALUE: "$( ${{ variableName }} )" # THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!
            displayName: Generate file for ${{ variableName }}
      - bash: tree secrets/ -a
        displayName: Display the generated secrets


For some weird reason, i cant assing a value to SECRET_VALUE using this syntax "$( ${{ variableName }} )"
What im trying to do, for each item inside parameters.targetVariables, set the value of SECRET_VALUE to $(variableName), and then echo $SECRET_VALUE into a file.
Is there any way i can do $(myVariableNameHere), but without actually hardcoding myVariableNameHere, and instead using the variable from the each loop (called variableName)?

As Rui Jarimba's answer, you need to change the env format to ENV_VALUE: $(${{ variableName }}) to get the secret variable in variable group based on parameter value.
In addition, you need to make the following changes in YAML to achieve your goal.
1.You need to change the bash script:
From:
echo $SECRET_VALUE > ./secrets/${variableName}.txt

To
echo $SECRET_VALUE > ./secrets/${{variableName}}.txt

Then it will generate the txt file based on variable name.
2.You need to change the SECRET Key word in the environment variable in bash task.
For example:
SECRET_VALUE -> MAPPED_VALUE
Based on my test, if the env variable contains the SECRET Key word, it will return the empty value.
Here is the full yaml sample:
pool:
  vmimage: ubuntu-latest
parameters:
  - name: targetVariables
    type: object
    default:
     - shared-smtp-user
     - shared-ldap-password

variables:
- group:  variablegroupname



jobs:
  - job: echo_secret_files
    displayName: ️ Echo secret files
    steps:
      - checkout: none
      - bash: |
          echo "Echoing targetVariables into secrets/"
          echo "using targetVariables ${{ convertToJson(parameters.targetVariables) }}"
          mkdir -p ./secrets/
          echo $(shared-smtp-user)
        displayName: Display information about the secrets being used
      - ${{ each variableName in parameters.targetVariables }}:
          - bash: |
              echo $MAPPED_VALUE > ./secrets/${{variableName}}.txt
            env:
               MAPPED_VALUE: $(${{ variableName }}) 
            displayName: Generate file for ${{ variableName }}
   
      - bash: tree secrets/ -a
        displayName: Display the generated secrets

Result:


Both you and Rui Jarimba are right, thanks! that solved it

The macro syntax for accessing a variable is $(var) (without white-space), not $( var ).
So instead of:
SECRET_VALUE: "$( ${{ variableName }} )"

Try:
SECRET_VALUE: $(${{ variableName }})

Example
Running some tests using a Linux build agent:
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

parameters:
  - name: variables
    displayName: Name of variables
    type: object
    default:
      - foo

variables:
  - name: foo
    value: Foo Value

jobs:
  - job: A
    displayName: Job A
    steps:
      - checkout: none

      - ${{ each variable in parameters.variables }}:
          - script: echo "${{ variable }}=$CURRENT_VAR" # Output: foo=$( foo )
            displayName: 'Echo ${{ variable }}'
            env:
              CURRENT_VAR: $( ${{ variable }} )  # <--------------- WITH SPACES

          - script: echo "${{ variable }}=$CURRENT_VAR" # Output: foo=Foo Value
            displayName: 'Echo ${{ variable }}'
            env:
              CURRENT_VAR: $(${{ variable }})    # <--------------- WITHOUT SPACES


both you and Kevin Lu-MSFT are right, thank you!!
